# Сделать картинку статичной

Tags: html, css

[image: http://prntscr.com/ajl4wh]

При наведении на картинку, она двигается и убирается рамка. Нужно, чтобы картинка оставалась статичной. Как это сделать?

P.S.: использую `position: fixed` или `position: absolute` - всё едет

Comment: Пожалуйста, разместите пример прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Не нужно делать скриншоты кода. Вместо этого копируйте в вопрос сам код. (А то можно в ответ получить скриншот решения).

Answer (score 3):

Это логично. Рамка(border) тоже формирует размер элемента, и он изменяются при её убирании - соответственно элемент сдвигается.

Просто сделайте рамку прозрачной, не убирая её:

```css
#container img {
  border: 25px solid black;
}

#container img:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/125/any" alt="какая-то картинка">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

размеры элемента не включают себя размер границы border поэтому при добавлении границы размер элемента изменяется и он в свою очередь отодвигается. Если прописать в css "box-sizing:border-box;" то алгоритм вычисления размера элемента изменится и размер элемента будет включать в себя также размер border.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Неудачный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: silver;
  border: 1em solid blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}

div:first-child:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}

div:first-child + div:hover {
  border: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div><div>2</div>
```